# Scaling images is not working inside TYPO3

Tags: typo3, imagemagick-convert

I have some trouble to make TYPO3 scale images.

If I test tin the Install tool, Combining images is working, but scaling images is not.

If I create a test file in the root directory of the server with a small Convert test, the images is scaled nicely.

When scaling in Install tool I get this error:

```
Image generation failed
ImageMagick / GraphicsMagick handling is enabled, but the execute command returned an error. Please check your settings, especially ['GFX']['im_path'] and ['GFX']['im_path_lzw'].
```

My configuration in TYPO3:

```
'GFX/image_processing' => '1'
'GFX/im' => '1'
'GFX/im_path' => '/usr/local/bin/safe/'
'GFX/im_path_lzw' => '/usr/local/bin/safe/'
'GFX/im_version_5' => 'im6'
'GFX/im_v5effects' => '0'
'GFX/im_mask_temp_ext_gif' => '1'
'GFX/colorspace' => 'RGB'
```

TYPO3 v. 6.2.5
Bootstrap-Package installed

I have Googled, but can't find the right solution

Comment: Via ssh, what does `which convert` say?

Comment: I'm on a shared server, so I guess I don't have SSH. But the ImageMagick version is: ImageMagick 6.6.7-1

Comment: What does your hoster say about the path then? Have you tried `/usr/local/bin/`, which is kind of the normal location? And, do you have GD? Can be a viable alternative.

Comment: Acording to my hoster, I use the right path. Yes, I have GD, but I thought IM was better, and I can't figure out why IM doesn't work indside TYPO3 when it does outside. As a matter of fact, I haven't any solutions since TYPO3 6.0 where IM is working proberly. I use the same host for all my sites and before TYPO3 6.0 there were no problems.

Comment: sorry, no idea what's wrong there. I would try GD, I'm not that sure if IM is really superior for basic tasks. Although I think GD can't create images from PDFs. Do you have live 4.5 versions on the same host still? So you could exclude it being a coincidence

Comment: Yes, I have 4.5 versions on same host.